# Что такое "высокая проходимость" по отношению к ресторану?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

> К тому же у ресторана высокая проходимость, так что все свежее
>   обеспечено, как и ловкие официанты в хорошем расположении духа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как ни странно, это **не** посещаемость ресторана, а (в жаргонном смысле) количественная оценка его местоположения - какое потенциальное число посетителей он способен привлечь. Буквально - сколько человек в день **проходит** мимо поблизости, в зоне прямой видимости ресторана и т. п.

http://allcafe.ru/profy/rexplorer/market/marketing/sum_guest

https://moluch.ru/archive/30/3486/

**P.S.** Пример материала, в котором сознательно разделяют **посещаемость** и **проходимость**, давая соотв. количественные характеристики тому и другому:

https://business-opening.ru/business/open-restoran/how-search-place-for-the-restaurant/

Можно заключить, что **посещаемость** ресторана зависит от его репутации, **проходимость** - только от местоположения. В исходном предложении слово использовано в несвойственном ему значении посещаемости.

Answer (score 1):

В этом контексте "хорошая проходимость", значит, что около ресторана проходит большое количество людей. Правда, относительно ресторана (если он не быстрого питания), подобная характеристика звучит странно, так как в таком заведении обычно народу немного, но сидят они долго, делая заказ на большие суммы. А вот для кафе, столовой или закусочной, куда приходят именно чтоб поесть, а не посидеть отдохнуть, высокая проходимость очень даже важна.

Answer (score 1):

Проходимость - это пропускная способнось, и то в основном относится к медицине, остальное - сленг. Не лучше ли сказать "посещаемость"?

Answer (score 1):

Хорошая проходимость  ― это именно хорошая пропускная способность (как у трубы). Сколько ни придет народу ― всех обслужим быстро и качественно, очередей нет, а свободные места всегда найдутся.  Поэтому всё съедается, ничего не залеживается, продукты всегда свежие.

Comment: Логика предложения указывает на _посещаемость_ (старое съедают, и продукты не залёживаются), Но это говорит лишь о том, что авторы придали слову, которое слышали в силу своей приобщённости к делу, не свойственное ему значение. _Пропускная способность_ в эту логику не вписывается: требуемое количество продуктов под полную загрузку всегда можно предусмотреть.